# Handling special case of calendar with PHP/Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, date, calendar

I know that the problem depicted in my last topic (Customizing date within PHP and Javascript) is a bit cryptic, but it is the reality though! So, I try to explain once more again but without entering into further details. How can I handle dates through PHP or Javascript with the assumption that all months have 30 days long? Should I create my own calendar? If yes. How?

Comment: What exactly do you want do? If all months are 30 days long, you don't need a lot of special functionality..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customizing date within PHP and Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232481/customizing-date-within-php-and-javascript)

Comment: Changing a few words around doesn't change the fact that this is the same question as before, and that one was closed. So... voting to close this one too.

Comment: You're going to find difficulty getting someone to provide a solution for this for a number of reasons. 1) Months are not all 30 days long, they just aren't, 2) Even if there was a way to do this, it will be hacky as you are trying to redefine the Gregorian calendar, 3) You will have 5.25 days remainder at the end of each year which will stuff your maths up. It's just an ugly, ugly, ugly problem and will produce an even uglier solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be extremely ugly...

For a specified date to be converted to the **Mohammed SETTI Calendar** (a year comprising of 12.175 months of 30 days each):

```
$theDate = strtotime( '1 April 2011' );

$dayOfYear = date( 'z' , $theDate )+1; # As it is zero-indexed, have to add one

echo 'In Indiana, that date would be '.
       date( 'Y' , $theDate ).'-'.
       ( floor( $dayOfYear/30 )+1 ).'-'. # As this, too, would be zero-indexed, +1
       ( $dayOfYear%30 );
```

See [this link](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/805/did-a-state-legislature-once-pass-a-law-saying-pi-equals-3) if you don't get the Indiana reference.

Surprisingly, April Fool's Day is one of the few days for which this returns the same details as the standard calendar.